# Estimate latent states for a Bernoulli stace space model, when the latent states follow an AR(1) process

Tags: categorical-data, state-space-models

I am dealing with this model

> $$y_t|\alpha_t \sim Bernoulli \left( \frac{\exp (\alpha_t)}{ 1+ \exp(\alpha_t)} \right) $$ with $\alpha_t = \phi \alpha_{t-1} + \epsilon_t,$ where $\epsilon_t \sim Normal\left(0, \frac{1}{\tau}\right)$.

**My goal is the estimation of:**  $\alpha_t|y_{1:T}$, where $T$ is the sample size.

I have estimated this model using MCMC. The problem is that I think that my results are suspicious (see please the image)!

**My question is:** Is there a routine that I could use for this goal?

Thank you in advance.

[image]